# Posible error con comando para migrar tablas

Tags: php, laravel

Una vez realizada la configuración de los ficheros `Factory` y al ejecutar el comando `php artisan migrate:fresh --seed`, se borran las tablas y se vuelven a crear, pero el proceso queda detenido al momento de generar los registros. No da ningún mensaje de error.

> Dropped all tables successfully. Migration table created successfully.
>   Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
>   Migrated: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
>   Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
>   Migrated: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
>   Migrating: 2020_05_01_185416_create_teachers_table
>   Migrated: 2020_05_01_185416_create_teachers_table
>   Migrating: 2020_05_01_205158_create_students_table
>   Migrated: 2020_05_01_205158_create_students_table
>   Migrating: 2020_05_01_205417_create_levels_table
>   Migrated: 2020_05_01_205417_create_levels_table
>   Migrating: 2020_05_01_205643_create_categories_table

Así queda la consola, como si el proceso no finalizara nunca.

Comment: Muéstranos que tienes en esa última migración create_categories_table y en los seeds

Comment: Ya lo pude realizar, les comento que no existía ningún error dentro del código, pero el proceso de rellenar las tablas con registros, no se por qué demoró como una hora. Otro colega probó y tuvo la misma demora. Saludos.